# Can someone explain this VBA macro code for me in English?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

```
Sub Seperate_Item_Codes_and_Descriptions()

'Seperate the item codes and the descriptions and put them in respectively in columns D and E.

Dim s As Long, a As Long, aVALs As Variant

With Worksheets(1)
    aVALs = .Range(.Cells(12, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
    ReDim Preserve aVALs(LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1), 1 To 2)
    For a = LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1)
        s = InStr(1, aVALs(a, 1), Chr(32))
        aVALs(a, 2) = Mid(aVALs(a, 1), s + 1)
        aVALs(a, 1) = Left(aVALs(a, 1), s - 1)
    Next a
    .Cells(12, "D").Resize(UBound(aVALs, 1), UBound(aVALs, 2)) = aVALs
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As the comment to your `sub` mentions `Seperate the item codes and the descriptions and put them in respectively in columns D and E`.

Answer (score 5):

Bit lazy... just read the code:

```
'//Procedure name.
Sub Seperate_Item_Codes_and_Descriptions()

'//A comment.
'Seperate the item codes and the descriptions and put them in respectively in columns D and E.

'//Setting up the variables.
Dim s As Long, a As Long, aVALs As Variant

'//Everything between this statement and End With that starts with a '.' will apply to the
'//first worksheet in the workbook (if you rearrange the order of sheets it will still look
'//at the tab that appears first in the workbook).
With Worksheets(1)

    'Get all values in the range B12 to last row containing data in column B and place in an array.
    'Value2 is the same as Value except it doesn't use Currency or Date formats.
    'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182812
    'The array will be: aVALS(1 to rownum,1 to 1)
    'Use aVALS(1,1) for first value, aVALS(2,1) for second value.
    'NB:  If the last row is higher up than row 12 you'll get unexpected results.
    aVALs = .Range(.Cells(12, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

    'Update the last dimension of the array, while keeping the original values so its: aVALS(1 to rownum, 1 to 2)
    'Use aVALS(1,1) is first value, aVALS(1,2) is empty, aVALS(2,1) is second value...
    ReDim Preserve aVALs(LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1), 1 To 2)

    'Step through the first dimension of the array (the 1 to rownum bit).
    For a = LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1)

        'Find the location of the first space in the element of the dimension being looked at.
        'Chr(32) is an Ascii space... I think.
        s = InStr(1, aVALs(a, 1), Chr(32))

        'Split the array by space and repopulate the array.
        'Will now read as aVALS(1,1) = text to left of space, aVALS(1,2) = text to right of space.
        aVALs(a, 2) = Mid(aVALs(a, 1), s + 1)
        aVALs(a, 1) = Left(aVALs(a, 1), s - 1)
    Next a

    'Paste the array of split text back into the first worksheet in column D & E.
    .Cells(12, "D").Resize(UBound(aVALs, 1), UBound(aVALs, 2)) = aVALs
End With

End Sub
```